# weight inputs in Fuzzy Logic System

Tags: matlab, logic, fuzzy

I am using the fuzzy logic designer app on matlab 2022a to create an output score from 0 to 100 from input variables also ranging from 0 to 100.

I saw that it is possible to weight the rules but does anyone know if it is possible to associate a weight to the input variables? For instance if there are two variables A and B, is it possible to configurate the fuzzy logic system such as variable A is taken into account 10 times more than B instead of equally? Currently I have been trying mostly Mandami models.

Any help would be super appreciated,

[image]

[image]